# Warnings during compilation of some old C++ software (format expects type int, argument has int32)

Tags: c++, g++, format, int, scanf

I want to compile some C++ software that one can [download here](http://ftp3.itu.ch/av-arch/video-site/0109_San/VCEG-N80_software.zip). It's from 2001. Running `make` should do the trick.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 and I had to change `gcc` in the makefile to `g++` for compilation  to work.

#### Warnings:

Now, the program needs to scan a parameter file. When I compile, I receive several warnings:

```
g++    -c -o packet_data_agent.o packet_data_agent.cpp
packet_data_agent.cpp: In constructor ‘PACKET_DATA_AGENT::PACKET_DATA_AGENT()’:
packet_data_agent.cpp:34: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
packet_data_agent.cpp: In member function ‘void PACKET_DATA_AGENT::initialize(FILE*, FILE*)’:
packet_data_agent.cpp:109: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp:128: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int*’, but argument 3 has type ‘int32*’
packet_data_agent.cpp:131: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp:136: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp:141: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int*’, but argument 3 has type ‘int32*’
packet_data_agent.cpp:144: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp:149: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp: In member function ‘int32 PACKET_DATA_AGENT::get_PDU(int32, VIRTUAL_PDU*)’:
packet_data_agent.cpp:213: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp:244: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp: In member function ‘void PACKET_DATA_AGENT::put_PDU(int32, VIRTUAL_PDU*)’:
packet_data_agent.cpp:312: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp: In member function ‘void PACKET_DATA_AGENT::write_statistics(FILE*)’:
packet_data_agent.cpp:393: warning: format ‘%10d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int32’
packet_data_agent.cpp:394: warning: format ‘%10d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int32’
g++ -O4  mobile_ip.o loss_generator.o radio_link_agent.o packet_data_agent.o -o mobile_ip -lm
```

#### My Problem:

Those lead to the fact that I can't parse the included settings file. In the `packet_data_agent.h`, the variable is declared as `int32`:

```
int32 compressed_Internet_header_size;
```

And the C++ code to scan the parameter file in `packet_data_agent.cpp:128`:

```
fscanf(ParameterFile_ptr,"- compressed RTP/UDP/IP header size (in bytes): %d\n",&compressed_Internet_header_size);
```

But when I run the program, I receive the following error:

```
!!error in module PACKET-DATA-AGENT: illegal value 0 for the compressed RTP/UDP/IP header size
```

Although the parameter file clearly has:

```
- compressed RTP/UDP/IP header size (in bytes): 3
```

What can I do to make the program correctly parse the parameter file?

#### Additional information:

- Size of `int` on my platform is 4

Here's my g++ version:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

#### Some very simple debugging:

I changed the source code as follows:

```
int return_test = fscanf(ParameterFile_ptr,"- compressed RTP/UDP/IP header size (in bytes): %d\n",&compressed_Internet_header_size);
printf ("%d\n", return_test);
printf ("%d\n", compressed_Internet_header_size);
```

The output is 0, 0. What could that mean? I mean, seriously, it's right in front of me and it won't find the parameter?

Comment: What's the size of `int` on that platform?

Comment: Well, my answer *would* have been that the code expects to be compiled 32-bit and you're compiling 64-bit, but that g++ -v suggests otherwise. int32 should just be typedef for int, so it's very odd to see this warning at all.  I think that's a clue, I just can't figure out to what!

Comment: A dumb way would be to use `printf( "d\n", sizeof(int) );` somewhere near start of `main()`.

Comment: @sharptooth I added it to my question above. Thanks.

Comment: With 4-bytes `int` that's something I can't explain.

Comment: @sharptooth And the proper way would be to use std::cout :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The warnings**:

The header `global.h` makes `int32` a synonym for `long`. gcc is issuing warnings when you pass a `long` into `*printf` with format code `%d` because on some platforms (any where an `int` is 32 bits and a `long` is 64, or where an `int` is 16 bits and a `long` is 32) that will have very bad results.

You could just change the typedef so that `int32` means `int` rather than `long` and probably nothing bad will happen.

**The actual error when run**:

[EDITED in the light of new information from original question-asker:]

It doesn't seem that this has anything to do with the `int`/`long`/`int32` stuff: rather, `fscanf` is failing to read that line of the parameter file. What about earlier lines? Is `fscanf` returning 1 for them all, or is it actually going wrong earlier in a way that doesn't make it stop trying to parse the file?

*Assuming that all the earlier `fscanf` calls are succeeding and this is the first failing one*: What happens if you copy-and-paste the fixed boilerplate stuff from the source code into the file? What if you make it just look for a number without any of the fixed boilerplate text? There aren't any other lines in your parameter file between the `file containing the output RTP stream` line and the `compressed RTP/UDP/IP header size` line, are there?

You may be able to get some idea of where it's failing as follows: After the offending `fscanf` call, read a bit of the parameter file using `fread`, display it, and exit (no point trying to continue, of course; the parser will be completely confused if you do). If, e.g., it's failed because it ran across a character that didn't match the constant text in the `fscanf` format string, this should give you the non-matching character and some of what follows. If it's failed because it tried to read an integer and saw something it didn't like, then you should get the first character it couldn't interpret as part of an integer and some of what follows. Etc.

Comment: I should really get into the habit of refreshing the page before typing an answer :p

Comment: I changed the source accordingly and fscanf returns 0, the parameter read is 0, too, obviously.

Comment: "There aren't any other lines in your parameter file between the .. and the ... line, are there?" **No** - there was one that wasn't parsed at all! I swear, if I ever meet the developer of this software ...

Comment: Yeah, it's an ... interesting ... way of parsing a config file :-).

Answer (score 2):

In order to be portable, you should use the format string macros from [inttypes.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inttypes.h):

```
int32_t myint;
... = scanf("%" SCNi32, %myint);
```